# How to say "Should I [do something]?"

Tags: grammar, nuances

There was a similar question here, but it was more along the lines of "Should we do something together?", and I'm not sure it fits my case. For example, how do you say "Should I bring something to the meeting?"
I came up with these options:

> 1) 会議で何か必要な物はありますか？
>   2) 会議に何か必要ですか？
>   3) 会議に持っていくべき物はありますか？
>   4) 会議に何か持っていきますか?
>   5) 会議に何か持っていきましょうか?

Can you please tell me a) which ones are correct/more natural and b) which are the nuances of each?
I'm especially confused by ~ましょうか because I usually see it used as "shall we [do something]?" in the sense of an invitation, but I can't figure out whether it's ok to use it in my case.

Comment: 何か**に** in #4 and #5 is incorrect. Maybe you meant to type just 何か ?

Comment: Thank you. I changed it to を as another user suggested, but now I'm confused about whether I should use it or no particle at all. I still have a hard time with them.

Comment: 「何か持っていきますか？/行きましょうか？」(with no を) のほうが自然だと思います。（Btw as for #3 I would rather say 「会議に持っていくものはありますか？」(with no べき) in normal conversation)

Comment: So, as far as #3 goes, there isn't any special way to convey the "Should I..." nuance, but it gets across to listeners anyway?

Comment: For #5, I would say 何かを...   ,  #4: Doesn't sound right. Suggest
 「何かを持って行った方がいいですか？」.  Actually, in most situations, you would act like you are going to bring something, but you don't know what it should be, as in 「会議に何を持っていけばいいですか？

Comment: @Simona そうですね。。You can say 持っていくもの(things to bring), すること(things to do), 買うもの(things to buy), 覚えること(things to remember) etc... (to mean するべきこと, 買うべきもの, 覚えるべきこと etc.)

Comment: ^ user27280, ４番、別におかしくないと思いますけど・・「何かを持って行った方がいいですか？」も通常は「を」はつけないですね・・「会議に何を持っていけばいいですか？」は"Should I bring something?"じゃなくて"What should I bring?"になりますけど・・

Comment: @Chocolate なるほどね。「何を持っていけばよいのですか？」とか「何を持参すれべよろしいですか？」ってどう？

Comment: ^ それも両方、"Should I bring something?" じゃなくて "What should I bring?" になる気がするんですけど、いいんでしょうかね・・・

Comment: @Chocolate thank you for the explanation. Also, if I understood the conversation that was going on in Japanese correctly, what I wanted to say is "Should I bring something?" (I don't know if I should bring something; people may say no), as opposed to "What should I bring?" (I know I need to bring something but I don't know what).

Comment: @Simona  I assumed that you were referring to bringing something for the group (beverages, etc.). The point that I was trying to make is that, even when you are pretty sure that nobody expects or needs you to bring anything, demonstrates your desire to be helpful and generous will ingratiate you with your coworkers and higher-ups.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand correctly something like this:

会議に何か持って行ったほうがいいでしょうか。

or

会議に準備しておくものが要りますか。

Comment: 「準備しておくものが要りますか。」 sounds unnatural/incorrect.

Comment: Could be! I just wrote it down from what I hear from working/living in Japan. Doesn't mean I'm right. Do you have something that shows it's incorrect?

Comment: 文法的にも「用意/準備しておくものは**ありますか** 」ですよね。`Do you have something that shows it's incorrect?`→ 「準備/用意しておくものが**要りますか** 。」は文法もおかしいですし、そういう言い方はしません。"しておくものは要りますか"をググったらヒット数ゼロ、"しておくもの**が**要りますか"でヒットするのはこの投稿一件だけです。ひらがなで「～いりますか」で試しても、「が」「は」いずれの場合もヒット数ゼロです。

Comment: そこそこ日本語使いこなせるわりに、日本人の優しい教え方把握できんみたいな。生き延びるため、精神的にも成長せんとな。これから、自分の知っとることを鼻にかけるんじゃなくて、他人にもっと優しい接し方をやってみったらと思うけど

Comment: すいません、私、純生の日本人で日本語母語話者なんですけど、「そこそこ日本語が使いこなせる」って私のことですか？　「日本人の優しい教え方把握できんみたいな」って、どういう意味でしょうか・・・　知っていることを鼻にかけたつもりはないですけど、「Do you have something that shows it's incorrect?」 って、「間違ってるということを示すものはありますか？」っていう意味だと思ったので、グーグルで検索してヒット数を調べました。英語を読み間違えていたらすみません。